# Facebook Login with custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, python-social-auth, django-custom-user

m trying to create a new user with Social-Auth and my custom user model required a phone number but facebook does not allow it

so i get this error

```
TypeError at /social-auth/complete/facebook/
create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'phone'
```

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXX'       
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email'] # add this
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {       
  'fields': 'id, name, email, picture.type(large), link'
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA = [                 
    ('name', 'name'),
    ('email', 'email'),
    ('picture', 'picture'),
    ('link', 'profile_url'),
]
```

how can i pass a default parameter to avoid this error or any solution to work around this problem

Comment: Show some code from views.py, urls.py and may be models too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 'username' the problem is that most propable you make the phone number required as a field in your User model.
And in pipeline in your SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE you've

> "social_core.pipeline.user.create_user"

It tries to create a user if it's not found in your Db. So I think you've 2 options.
1-Make phone number in your model not required.
2-Remove this pipeline and create your own pipeline with your own implementation.